# how to start reading excel file skipping he first line of excel file?

Tags: java, excel

```
public void doConvertFileAmazon(String pathFolderRead, String pathFolderWrite, String bpcnum) throws Exception {
        Collection<File> listFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(pathFolderRead), new String[] { "xlsx" }, false);
        for (File file : listFiles) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            List<String[]> listRow = ExcelWriter.read(file, 22);
            for (String[] cols : listRow) {
                sb.append("BEV01;SRN;;" + bpcnum + ";SL;" + cols[3] + ";" + cols[0] + ";" + cols[1] + ";" + cols[13]
                        + ";" + cols[17] + ";1;;\r\n");
            }
            String filename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName());
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(pathFolderWrite, filename + ".csv"), sb.toString(), "UTF-8");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this question for several solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710059/java-foreach-skip-first-iteration .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java foreach skip first iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710059/java-foreach-skip-first-iteration)

Comment: how i can read only one line of the file?